# loading specific id content from html in dojo content pane

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am trying to load specific html id content in Dojo content pane on click of a tree node.
I have a long html, which has several headings. I am trying to load content from this html on click on a tree node. I am able to get html loaded, but I am not able to bring content with specific id on top of content pane.

Say my html is `abc.html` and it has several ids say `id1`, `id2` ...
if I open this html in IE with argument `abc.html`, page gets loaded, with first line on top. Now if I open it with argument `abc.html#id9`
This specific section of html get loaded to top of IE window.

I am trying to achieve same effect in dojo content pane - here content is loaded in Dojo ContentPane on click on tree node and goal is load specific `#id` associated with that tree node in content pane, instead of loading top of html.

It never loads specific id content on top of content pane. It always load as if argument is `abc.html`. I do not see any effect of `abc.html#id9`

below is code snippet on how I am creating content pane and loading content on click on tree node.

```
....

   var CenterPane = new  ContentPane({//content pane at center for loading urls of selected designs
     content:"Click to get the details about node",
     region:"center"});
   bordContainer.addChild(CenterPane);//add content pane to the border container

....
....

var fileTree = new Tree ({
            model: treeModel,
            showRoot: false,
            openOnClick:true,
            autoExpand:false,
            _createTreeNode: function (args)
              {   
                return new MyTreeNode(args);
              },
             onClick: function(args) {

CenterPane.set("href", vHtmlPath); }

....
```

`vHtmlPat`h is dynamically set to `abc.html#id9` or `abc.html#id1` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentPane does not load into an iframe. If you want to move, you have to change the current page url.
For instance

```
CenterPane.set("href", vHtmlPath).then(function() {
    document.location.href = "#id9"
}
```